# razor pages: retrieve results from select list

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have this selectlist in my app:

```
<select name="selectList" id="ourselect" style="outline:auto !important;" asp-items="Model.Options"></select>
```

It gets bound to this property:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
```

The resulting page looks like this:

[image]

So, what happens?

Basically the user can select a language fromt he select on the left and then add it to the languages he speaks on the right (sprache hinzufügen = add language in german).

THis is is all done in the frontend with a lot jquery.

The issue now is that I need to retrieve the values selected (which can be multiple) that are visible on the right.
But as all of this is done in the frontend, I dont really know how to get the "values selected" from this list?

Also, whenever a langauge is picked, I save in the frontend what language level the user is on and also if it is a nice to have or musthave (as all seen in the frontend).

THis is how I add the children to the right side layout_

```
if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) 
            {
                const clone = document.querySelector('#pickedLan').content.cloneNode(true);
                let p = clone.querySelectorAll("p");
                let button = clone.querySelectorAll("button");
                let mainDiv = clone.querySelectorAll(".findme");
                var idtodel = "#" + selected.val().trim()

                if ($(idtodel).length) {

                   alert('Bitte wähle eine noch nicht gewählte Sprache aus. Wenn du Änderungen vornehmen willst, dann kannst du die gewählte Sprache auch jederzeit neu löschen.')
                   return; 
                }

                p[0].innerHTML = selected.text()
                p[1].innerHTML = radioLanquality;
                p[2].innerHTML = radioMustHaveResult;

                // add id to main div to be deleteable
                mainDiv[0].id = selected.val().trim()

                // add button to delete
                button[0].addEventListener('click', () => {    
                    $(idtodel).remove()
                    counterOfElemensAdded--;
                    EnableOrDisbableButton();
                });

                document.querySelector("#pickedLingua").appendChild(clone);
            }
```

How would I retrieve all this information in my controller?

Any ideas?